# EncryptedSessionProxy not working in symfony 3.4?

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to do an encryption of session data
 as per the official instruction, but it does not work. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My EncryptedSessionProxy

```
namespace SecurityBundle\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy;

class EncryptedSessionProxy extends SessionHandlerProxy
{
    private $key;

    public function __construct( \SessionHandlerInterface $handler, $key)
    {
        $this->key = $key;

        parent::__construct($handler);
    }

    public function read($id)
    {
        $data = parent::read($id);

        return mcrypt_decrypt(\MCRYPT_3DES, $this->key, $data,'ecb');
    }

    public function write($id, $data)
    {  
        $data = mcrypt_encrypt(\MCRYPT_3DES, $this->key, $data,'ecb');

        return parent::write($id, $data);
    }

}
```

My service.yml

```
security.encrypt_native_session:
        class: SecurityBundle\Session\EncryptedSessionProxy
        arguments: ['@session.handler.native_file','secret_string']
```

My config.yml

```
session:
    handler_id:  security.encrypt_native_session
```